# Generate "aa", "Aa", "aA", "AA", etc In order

Tags: vb.net

How would I generate combinations of 2 lowercase/upercase letters/numbers in order?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Looper As Boolean = True

    While Looper = True
        'String = "aa", "Aa", "aA", "AA"
        'WebClient.DownloadString("link.com/" & String")
    End While

End Sub
```

Like this, but generate combination for String

Comment: Why do you need to generate these combinations?  I ask this so we can ensure we're not addressing a small part of a larger problem.

Comment: No other problems, just wondering how I can generate something like that.

Comment: Random letters/numbers?

Comment: Does this need to continue in its pattern beyond 2 characters? For example after zZ, ZZ, aaa, Aaa, aAa, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over a string and just manipulate upper and lower case as required:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim results as List(of String) = new List(of String)()

    For Each c as Char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
        results.Add(c.ToString().ToLower() & c.ToString().ToLower())
        results.Add(c.ToString() & c.ToString().ToLower())
        results.Add(c.ToString().ToLower() & c.ToString())
        results.Add(c.ToString() & c.ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a combination of two random characters, including numbers and uppercase/lowercase letters:

```
Public Function GetRandomString(ByVal iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim rdm As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 1 To iLength
        sResult &= ChrW(rdm.Next(32, 126))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

---

Or you can do the common random string defining the valid caracters:

```
Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim rdm As New Random()
    Dim allowChrs() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim sResult As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
        sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```